# OpenGL Draw Multiple Vertex Arrays

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer, vertex-array-object

I want to draw multiple vertex arrays. This is the initialization:

```
unsigned int va1;
unsigned int vb1;

void init_va1() {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &va1);
    glBindVertexArray(va1);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vb1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(vec2), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(vec2), nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

unsigned int va2;
unsigned int vb2;

void init_va2() {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &va2);
    glBindVertexArray(va2);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vb2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(vec2), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(vec2), nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

At initialization:

```
init_va1();
init_va2();
```

At draw:

```
glBindVertexArray(va1);
vec2 a1[] = {
    vec2(0.0, 0.0),
    vec2(0.1, 0.0),
    vec2(0.1, 0.1),
    vec2(0.0, 0.1),
};
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(a1), a1);
glUniform3f(polygon_color_loc, 0, 1, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);

glBindVertexArray(va2);
vec2 a2[] = {
    vec2(0.0, 0.0),
    vec2(-0.1, 0.0),
    vec2(-0.1, -0.1),
    vec2(0.0, -0.1),
};
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(a2), a2);
glUniform3f(polygon_color_loc, 1, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
```

Whichever vertex array I initialize last will be drawn properly, and the other one will not be drawn. For example, if I call init_va1() and then init_va2(), the drawing using va2 will be shown, and the drawing using va1 will not. If I reorder the calls, then the drawing using va1 will be shown, and the drawing using va2 will not. How do I draw both vertex arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) changes the data of the buffer that is currently bound to the specified target. The current `ARRAY_BUFFER` is a globale state. you need to bind the proper buffer object when you want to update the data store of the buffer:

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb1);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(a1), a1);

glBindVertexArray(va1);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
```

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb2);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(a2), a2);

glBindVertexArray(va2);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
```

---

In contrast to the `ARRAY_BUFFER`, the [Index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) is stated in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). If you want to change the contents of an index buffer, it is also possible just to bind the the VAO in which the index buffer is stated.

Comment: "f you want to change the contents of an index buffer, you must bind the VAO in which the index buffer is stated." No. It is just a buffer like every other buffer. and you can use any VAO you want to access such a buffer as `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` - but you don't even need that, as you can bind the buffer to any other target if you only want to update its contents.